# Multiple sql table select

Tags: sql, select, join, multiple-tables, multiple-select

There are tables with clients and festivals. Every festival happens every year (like New Year). But not every client is invited on any festival.

I need to get woman clients, that were invited on festival1 at this moment, but weren't invited on festival2.

```
Table "clients"
+-----+--------------+-----------+---------+-----+
| id  | name         | email     | adress  | sex |
+-----+--------------+-----------+---------+-----+
| 1   | Ivan         | iva@ya.su | NY city | m   |
| 2   | Michael      | lad@ya.su | LA      | m   |
| 3   | Anna         | al@ya.su  | LA      | w   |
| ...
+-----+--------------+-----------+---------+-----+

Table festivals
+-----+------------+-------+
| id  | name       | date  |
+-----+------------+-------+
| 1   | festival1  | 8-03  |
| 2   | festival2  | 23-02 |
| 3   | festival3  | 1-01  |
| ...
+-----+------------+-------+

Talbe "invitations"
+--------+----------+------+
| client | festival | year |
+--------+----------+------+
| 1      | 2        | 2013 |
| 3      | 1        | 2009 |
| ...
+--------+----------+
```

I started to do something like this query, but it need to be corrected:

```
SELECT name
    FROM clients, festivals, invitations
    WHERE clients.sex = w
        AND festivals.name = festival1
        AND clients.id = invitations.client
        AND invitations.year = 2013
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is wrong with your query? What were you expecting and what did you get instead.

Comment: Unrelated, but although the join syntax you are using is not wrong, it is over 20 years out of date, and was replaced in ANSI 92 by explicit joins. Aaron Bertrand has made a much better case than I could here for switching to the newer join syntax https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` to eliminate results from your query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Clients
        INNER JOIN Invitations
            ON Invitations.Client = Clients.ID
        INNER JOIN Festivals
            ON Festivals.ID = Invitations.Festival
WHERE   Festivals.Name = 'Festival1'
AND     Clients.Sex = 'W'
AND     Invitations.Year = 2013
AND     NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    Invitations i2
                    INNER JOIN Festivals f2
                        ON f2.ID = i2.Festival
            WHERE   i2.Client = Clients.ID
            AND     f2.Name = 'Festival2'
            AND     i2.Year = Invitations.Year
        );
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92ced/1)**

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c.name
FROM clients c
INNER JOIN invitations i ON c.id = i.client
INNER JOIN festivals f ON f.id = i.festival 
WHERE c.sex = 'w'
AND i.year = 2013
group by c.name
having sum(case when f.name='festival1' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
and sum(case when f.name='festival2' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
SELECT c.Name
   FROM clients c
    INNER JOIN invitations i 
        ON i.client = c.id 
        AND i.year = 2013
    INNER JOIN festivals f 
        ON i.festival = f.id
        AND f.name = 'festival1'
WHERE 
    c.sex = 'w'
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. but this query will also take woman that were invited or weren't invited on festival2. i need only that weren't invited on festival2.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to join clients with festivals through:
 clients/invitations then invitations/festivals

Second you need to discard clients invited to festival2

```
SELECT name
    FROM clients, festivals, invitations
    WHERE clients.sex = w
        AND festivals.name = festival1
        AND festivals.name != festival2
        AND clients.id = invitations.client
        AND festivals.id = invitations.festival
        AND invitations.year = 2013
```